# A safe directory that can be used in Docker and a development environment

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a webapp which needs to store temporary files wherever it runs.
Since I want the app to execute both in Docker and in a development environment - I need a safe directory that can be created in the development environment (Mac OS usually) and in the Docker container.

I used `/usr/temp` on the container but on a mac this directory in inaccessible.

What would be the best, safest directory to use?

Thank you

Comment: Use a volume for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up having the following in my Dockerfile

```
ENV HOME /usr
WORKDIR $HOME/app
RUN mkdir -p $HOME/temp/abc \
             $HOME/temp/xyz
```

And in my configuration files, I used `/temp/abc` or `/temp/xyz` to point to the destination folders.

Finally, in my application code I made sure to prepend any path resolution with `process.env['HOME']` (NodeJS).

The above works well in both a development envirnment, since $HOME is set by default on a mac and also in production which runs the docker above.

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

If the environment variable `$TMPDIR` is set, it's a standard place for temporary files, and if it's not set, it usually defaults to `/tmp`.  (On MacOS it points to a per-user directory that quickly gets filled with clutter.)  You don't mention what language you're using, but most have a specific function or module to create a file "in the usual temporary directory", which is this one.

In general environment variables are a good way to encapsulate differences between your development and various deployment environments and it makes sense here.

Also remember, on the one hand, that anything in Docker filesystem space you don't explicitly persist will be lost when the container exits, and on the other, that if the container stays running for a long time, there isn't any sort of automated `/tmp` cleaner.  You'll need to properly manage the lifecycle of these files.  Also also remember that you have near-complete control over the container's filesystem layout and if you need some specific directory to exist you can `RUN mkdir` it in your Dockerfile.

Answer (score 0):

Docker provides volumes concept to help you sync up data between Host and Container.

In your case, lets say you want to sync `/home/user/data` from your **host** to `/usr/temp` in Container

you can do so like this

```
docker run -itd -v /home/user/data:/usr/temp --name mycontainer imagename
```

Once the container is up and running

Add some file in the `data` folder and it will be available inside the container in the `temp` folder and other way around.

Comment: Thanks, MyTwoCents but this is not exactly what I meant - bad wording on my side. What I meant is that I want to find a path which I can safely create on both the Docker container and the development machines - which are Macs. Looks like I'll have to use $HOME and make sure to create a directory on both the docker and the dev machines